# Adding parameters to style

Tags: wpf

I am trying to create a simple button:

```
<Style x:Key="ButtonStyle" TargetType="Button">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                <Border CornerRadius="0" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="#83a5d2" x:Name="border">
                    <Border.Background>
                        <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="0,1">
                            <GradientStop Color="#e8f1fe" Offset="0"/>
                            <GradientStop Color="#cbe1fe" Offset="0.5"/>
                            <GradientStop Color="#a3c7f1" Offset="0.50"/>
                            <GradientStop Color="#cceffe" Offset="1"/>
                        </LinearGradientBrush>
                    </Border.Background>
                    <ContentPresenter VerticalAlignment="Center" x:Name="contentPresenter"/>
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

But how can I change the CornerRadius? I want to be able to pass a property to the object so that the object will have that corner radius. I cannot use templatebinding because Button does not have a property called CornerRadius.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To bind the corner radius to a value you want to set programatically, you could declare it in your Xaml...

```
        <Style x:Key="ButtonStyle"  TargetType="Button">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                        <Border CornerRadius="{Binding MyCornerRadius}" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="#83a5d2" x:Name="border">
                            <Border.Background>
                                <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="0,1">
                                    <GradientStop Color="#e8f1fe" Offset="0"/>
                                    <GradientStop Color="#cbe1fe" Offset="0.5"/>
                                    <GradientStop Color="#a3c7f1" Offset="0.50"/>
                                    <GradientStop Color="#cceffe" Offset="1"/>
                                </LinearGradientBrush>
                            </Border.Background>
                            <ContentPresenter VerticalAlignment="Center" x:Name="contentPresenter"/>
                        </Border>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
```

Then create the button(s)...

```
        <Button Style="{StaticResource ButtonStyle}" Content="Hello" DockPanel.Dock="Top" />
```

And then in your code behind, you could set it...

```
    public CornerRadius MyCornerRadius { get; set; }
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = this;
        MyCornerRadius = new CornerRadius(5, 6, 6, 5);            
    }
```

And this will give the effect you're after.

Answer (score 3):

You can directly use the "Border.CornerRadius" property in your styles. For the sake of simplicity I skipped most other attributes:

```
 <Style x:Name="myBtnStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
     <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Normal" />
     <Setter Property="Border.CornerRadius" Value="3" />
     <!-- more... -->
     <Setter Property="Template">
          <Setter.Value>
              <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
              <Border x:Name="bdContent" CornerRadius="{TemplateBinding Border.CornerRadius}">
                      <ContentPresenter Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" />
                  </Border>
              </ControlTemplate>
           </Setter.Value>
      </Setter>
  </Style>
```